# Keyboard disappeared! How can activate it?

Tags: keyboard

I got my new lumia 640 xl, everything is great except the keyboard! Sometimes the keyboard will hide and never back until shutting off and on again! 
Is it the problem? Or I have to some setting?

Comment: Have you tried a soft reset? (Holding Power+VolumeDown until it restarts.)

Comment: It should reappear as soon as you tap in any text box, like composing a new SMS. Does it not even do this?

Comment: Turn your Bluetooth off. It should fix it.

Comment: does your issue fixed or what did you do?